# How do I add a Windows user to the sysadmin server role in SQL Server 2022?

Tags: sql-server

I want to add user in sysadmins server roles in the Security configuration of the database in the SQL Server Management Studio.
When I click on sysadmin then there is no properties option showing how can I resolve this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2C1K.png)

When I click on sysadmin then there is no properties option showing how can I resolve this issue???

Comment: [`ALTER SERVER ROLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-server-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Are you using the latest SSMS version (19.1)?

Comment: yes its latest version 19.1

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [username];
```